# Does changing Google account password log me out of Gmail on Chrome?

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-chrome, passwords

I used a public computer to check my Gmail. I forgot to log out of the public computer. I have just changed my Google account password and I have always had 2 factor authentication enabled.

Will I now be logged out on that public computer (from the password change?). I was on Chrome Windows 10 for the public computer.

Comment: Changing your Google Account password does not disconnect any already logged into the account client, until they perform an action, that requires them to authenticate the account. However, unless you log out those clients, the device's cache can be accessed.

Comment: Scroll Gmail to bottom, in right corner click Details, then click on "Sign out from all other we sessions", see https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Chrome keep signed in if you forget to sign out. But you can sign out from all the devices any time.

From [Google Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> **Sign out from another computer**
>   If you forgot to sign out of your email on another computer, you can remotely sign out of Gmail.
>
> 1. Open [Gmail](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin).
> 2. In the bottom right corner, click **Details > Sign out all other web sessions**.